# Whenever user chooses option 3 "Quit" wont quit all the way out of Master loop. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Tags: c#, console

In the Showmenu, option 3 is to Quit, but app will not quit all the way out.It looks like it is returning the else statement from get menu option. Not sure why. If you run the application you will see.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text.Json;
    
    namespace NFLReportsApp
    {
        class Program
        {
            
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var searchFile = new ReadFromFile();
                var searchEngine = new PlayerSearchEngine();
                // searchEngine.Initialize();
    
                var keepSearching = true;
                while (keepSearching)
                {
                    ShowMenu();
                    var option = GetMenuOption();
                    switch (option)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            var allPlayers = searchEngine.GetAllPlayers();
                            DisplayPlayers(allPlayers);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            var searchName = GetPlayerSearchName();
                            var matchingPlayer = searchEngine.SearchPlayers(searchName);
                            DisplayPlayers(matchingPlayer);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            var searchText = GetTextSearch();
                            var matchingFile = searchFile.SearchFiles(searchText);
                            break;
    
                        case 4:
                            keepSearching = false;
                            return;
    
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
    
            private static object GetTextSearch()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            public static void DisplayPlayers(List<DisplayPlayers> allPlayers)
            {
                if (allPlayers.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No players found.");
                }
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var player in allPlayers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{++i}) {player.strPlayer}");
                }
            }
    
            public static string GetPlayerSearchName()
    
            {
    
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a players name:");
                    var searchName = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchName))
                    {
                        return searchName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid player name {searchName}");
                    }
                }
    
    
            }
    
            public static object GetMenuOption()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (Int32.TryParse(input, out var option))
                    {
                        return option;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Invalid solution {option}");
                        
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
    
    
            public static void ShowMenu()
            {
                var reader = new ReadFromFile();
                var engine = new PlayerSearchEngine();
                var keepSearching = true;
                while (keepSearching)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type: Search NFL Player, Cleveland Browns or Quit?");
    
                    var action = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (action == "Search NFL Player")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Which player would you like to search for?");
                        var Name = Console.ReadLine();
                        engine.SearchPlayers(Name);
                        engine.GetAllPlayers();
                    }
                    else if (action == "Cleveland Browns")
                    {
                        reader.ReadFromText();
                    }
                    else if (action == "Quit")
                    {
                        keepSearching = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //IS THERE A WAY TO ADD PLAYERS NAME TO CODE BELOW SO IT RETURNS INVALID
                        Console.WriteLine(action + " is not a valid command");
                    }
                }
          
    
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect time to learn to use the debugger and walk through the program as it runs.  Option 3 doesn't look like it quits anything.  `GetMenuOption` should probably return an integer, not an object.

Comment: If anything it seems like option 4 would break out of the loop / return from main. Are you sure that option 3 is "quit" and not option 4?

Comment: I'll have to try debugger out, dont think im too familiar with it @LarsTech

Comment: This is the option im talking about, that seems to quit out but it doesnt   }
                    else if (action == "Quit")
                    {
                        keepSearching = false;
                    } @FrederikHoeft

Comment: You would still have to hit "4".  "Quit" only gets you out of the child loop, not the parent loop.  Each `keepSearching` variable is local to their own code blocks.

Comment: hmm i tried using the debugger, didnt really know how to read it. Looks like it said the "keepSearching = false;" Is true.  Isnt Case 4 still returning false though? @LarsTech

Comment: Like I said, you have two separate `keepSearching` variables.  Each belong to their own loops.  Making one false does not make the other one false.  Maybe you want to change `ShowMenu` to return a string and inspect what you return in the master loop and decide what to do from there.

Comment: @Blare Robinson I see. Why not just promote `keepSearching` to a class member? just put a `private static bool keepSearching = true;` directly inside your `class Program` and remove all the other `var keepSearching` declarations from your methods. That way you can set it to false in `ShowMenu()` and it will also impact your loop in main.
You could also call `Environment.Exit(0)` but making `keepSearching` a class member would be more elegant.

Comment: I ended up using Environment.Exit to pass my program. But i am just now seeing your comment; i will 100% try making it a class member, as i am not finished with this certain project. Thanks for your advice, very helpful and less confusing ! @FrederikHoeft